# PHP ObjectId group a number of Ids

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb, where-clause

I have a two collections one of all the people I am following and another of what they have been posting on social networking sites like Twitter and Facebook.

The following collection has a subarray of the `_id` of the feed collection of each user which each status has the word `owner` and that has the ObjectId that the owner which is the same as the following key. Here is an example.

```
'_id' => new MongoId("REMOVED"),
  'following' => 
  array (
    '0' => 'ObjectId("53bf464ee7fda8780c8b4568")',
    '1' => 'ObjectId("53b00ab5e7fda8304b8b4567")',
  ),
  'owner' => new MongoId("53b9ea3ae7fda8863c8b4123"),
```

and in the feed you will see that the following.0 status below

```
array (
  '_id' => new MongoId("REMOVED"),
  'owner' => new MongoId("53bf464ee7fda8780c8b4568"),
  'status' => ' love this video - Pedigree Shelter dogs http://youtube.com/watch?v=5v5Ui8HUuN8',
  'timestamp' => new MongoDate(1405044327, 565000),
)
```

While I can loop through one by one, I can't for some reason do an $or search. I am not quite understanding how I loop through the following array and add it to the search query before I ran the query.

```
        collection = static::db()->feed;
        $where=array( '$or' => array(array('owner' => new MongoId($following.0)))));
        $feed = $collection->find($where);
        return $feed;
```

now I understand I will somehow have to loop the `$where=array( '$or' => array(array('owner' => new MongoId($following.0)))));` But I am just not 100% sure how to do this.

### Update

As per the answer below I had to edit the array that was returned - now I have only got this working manually and can't seem to get the PHP script to do it.

**Answer Returns**

```
Array ( [owner] => Array ( [$in] => Array ( [0] => new MongoId("53bf464ee7fda8780c8b4568") [1] => new MongoId("53b00ab5e7fda8304b8b4567") ) ) )
```

**Correct:**

```
Array ( "owner" => Array ( '$in' => Array ( "0" => new MongoId("53bf464ee7fda8780c8b4568"), "1" => new MongoId("53b00ab5e7fda8304b8b4567") ) ) )
```

I am not sure how else to get this to work.
current PHP

```
$collection = static::db()->following;
        $following = $collection->findOne(array ('owner' => new MongoId($_SESSION['user_information'][0]['_id'])));
        $follow = $following['following'];
        
        $collection = static::db()->feed;
        $where=array("owner" => array( '$in' =>$follow));
        print_r($where);
        $feed = $collection->find($where);
        print_r($feed);
        return $feed;
```

I have fixed a small issue with the collection and now the return array shows

```
Array ( [owner] => Array ( [$in] => Array ( [0] => MongoId Object ( [$id] => 53bf464ee7fda8780c8b4568 ) [1] => MongoId Object ( [$id] => 53b00ab5e7fda8304b8b4567 ) ) ) )
```

However, I still can't get it to return the feed like this one:

```
array (
  '_id' => new MongoId("53bf4667e7fda8700e8b4567"),
  'owner' => new MongoId("53bf464ee7fda8780c8b4568"),
  'status' => ' love this video - Pedigree Shelter dogs http://youtube.com/watch?v=5v5Ui8HUuN8',
  'timestamp' => new MongoDate(1405044327, 565000),
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am presuming here that this is just a PHPism in the way things are displayed and that your following array is an actual array and not a hash/map, which would generally look like this in a JSON representation:

```js
{ 
    "following": [
        ObjectId("53bf464ee7fda8780c8b4568"),
        ObjectId("53b00ab5e7fda8304b8b4567"),
    ],
    "owner": ObjectId("53b9ea3ae7fda8863c8b4123"),
}
```

In which case the "following" is already an actual array, and if you just want to `.find()` all the "feed" items for the people you are following, then you just pass that to the [**`$in`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) operator for your query selection:

```
$where = array( "owner" => array( '$in' => $following ) );
$feed = $collection->find($where);
return $feed;
```

The returned cursor will only contain results from the feed where the "owner" is present in your "following" array from the other collection item.

---

Watch this code:

```
$list = array(new MongoId(), new MongoId, new MongoId());
$doc = array( "owner" => array( '$in' => $list ));


echo json_encode( $doc, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT );
```

Despite how this serializes for JSON by this method the equivalent JSON is:

```
{
    "owner": {
        "$in": [
            ObjectId("53bf8157c8b5e635068b4567"),
            ObjectId("53bf8157c8b5e635068b4568"),
            ObjectId("53bf8157c8b5e635068b4569")
        ]
    }
}
```

That is how the BSON will serialize and is the correct query.

Comment: Small issue it seems that ObjectId is not correct it should be MongoId

Comment: @RussellHarrower JSON syntax as it appears in the shell. I did explicitly say that. I am trying to differentiate between PHP visualization of data structures and how the rest of the world sees them. And point was, "Is this actually a **real** array?" Or is it what the rest of us call a "hash" or "map" or "dict" or whatever?

Comment: here is the issue I have worked out with the above - it returns Array ( [owner] => Array ( [$in] => Array ( [0] => new MongoId("53bf464ee7fda8780c8b4568") [1] => new MongoId("53b00ab5e7fda8304b8b4567") ) ) ) but when it tried to run that as the $where query it does not work - it needs to be "owner" not [owner] as well as the other key parts - any suggestions

Comment: please see question I have added the error I am getting

Comment: @RussellHarrower I think you are misunderstanding this. I have added the BSON serialization for the code as given to clear that up.

Comment: @RussellHarrower It seems that you were not talking about just referencing the "field" value from your source document but in fact had the "cursor" that was returned from find. Your question does not include where the $following value is coming from. If you made that clear originally then that would have been easy to explain.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57153/discussion-between-russellharrower-and-neil-lunn).

Answer (score -1):

*(Answer added on behalf the question author to move it to the answer space).*

The issue was fixed when I used the following:

```
var_dump(iterator_to_array($feed));
```